# How to make a disk to boot to my Windows 7 folder?

Tags: windows-7, boot

Good day
I made a copy of my C: (system and boot drive Windows 7) to a new partition on a new disk. I made a Partition to partition copy, because the new disk had already data on it on second partition.
Now i want to disconnect the C:  drive.
How can i make my PC to boot from the new disk (to boot to the the new windows 7 partition)?
Thanks

Comment: You may need to boot Windows installation media and do a "repair" - reinstalling the Windows bootloader. BIOS installations require the MBR to be copied as well (UEFI installations require the whole EFI partition). Just copying the system partition isn't enough because it doesn't include the bootloader.

Comment: I will try to make this repair. I have tried to use the bcdboot command but no success. I wonder if the bcdedit command can help?

Comment: Did someone try easybcd software?

Answer (score -1):

How did you copy it? If you copy it by directly copying it and then pasting it will definitely not work.

We need to back up the operating system of the previous C drive to an image file by the ghost method, and then restore it to the new partition of the new disk. Through such a cloning method, "copy" the C drive to the new partition of the new disk. Then use bcdedit to fix the boot menu. After the repair is complete, there will be two startup items in the boot menu, choose to boot from the new partition of the new disk, then disconnect the C drive and boot from the C drive.

Comment: I used Partition Magic software to clone the C: partition to a new partition on a new disk.I made it Active. Then i used the bcdboot command. But still the new partition on the new diskvis not booting. Can you explain how to use bcdedit? .